# Algorithm that counts character's doesn't count apostrophes

Tags: c++, xcode, terminal

This is the function of a larger program.  This function just figures out how many characters are in an alphanumeric word.  Weird thing is, it counts apostrophes when running it in Xcode, but not after compiling and running it in Terminal.  Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int WordLength();
void DisplayTable(int WF[]);

int main()
{
    int WordFrequency[16]={0};
    int TempLengthStorage=0;

    TempLengthStorage=WordLength();

    while (TempLengthStorage!=0)
    {
        if (TempLengthStorage==1)//skipping subscript 0 - not using it
            ++WordFrequency[1];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==2)
            ++WordFrequency[2];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==3)
            ++WordFrequency[3];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==4)
            ++WordFrequency[4];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==5)
            ++WordFrequency[5];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==6)
            ++WordFrequency[6];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==7)
            ++WordFrequency[7];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==8)
            ++WordFrequency[8];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==9)
            ++WordFrequency[9];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==10)
            ++WordFrequency[10];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==11)
            ++WordFrequency[11];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==12)
            ++WordFrequency[12];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==13)
            ++WordFrequency[13];

        else if (TempLengthStorage==14)
            ++WordFrequency[14];

        else if (TempLengthStorage>=15)
            ++WordFrequency[15];

        TempLengthStorage=WordLength();
    }

    DisplayTable(WordFrequency);
}

int WordLength()
{
    int LetterCount=0;
    int EndOfWord=0;
    char Input;
    char NextChar;

    cin.get(Input);

    while (EndOfWord!=1 && !cin.eof())
    {
        if (Input==' ' || Input=='\n' || Input=='.' || Input=='!' || Input=='?'  || Input==',')
        {//do nothing if whitespace or punctuation, essentially skips over them
        }

        else if (Input=='-')
        {
            NextChar=cin.peek();

            if ((isalpha(NextChar)) || (isnumber(NextChar)))//this includes the hyphen in words that have hyphens (refer to funtion notes)
                ++LetterCount;

            if (NextChar=='\n')//for cases where the hyphen doesn't add to word length (refer to function notes)
            {
                cin.get(Input);//dont count it and get next character
            }
        }

        else if (Input=='\'')
            ++LetterCount;

        else if ((isalpha(Input)) || (isnumber(Input)))
        {
            ++LetterCount;

            NextChar=cin.peek();

            if (NextChar==' ' || NextChar=='\n' || NextChar=='.' || NextChar=='!' || NextChar=='?'  || NextChar==',' || NextChar==')')//included ) as a condition to end words for cases such as (219)
            {
                EndOfWord=1;
            }
        }

        cin.get(Input);
    }

    return LetterCount;
}

void DisplayTable(int WF[])
{
    int TotalWords=0;
    float TotalLetters=0;//made a float for float based masth later on when finding average
    float Average=0;

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Word Length                 Frequency" << endl;
    cout << "-----------                 ---------" << endl;

    for (int i=1; i<=15; ++i)
    {
        /*This portion of the loop displays the table*/

        cout << "    ";
        cout << setw(2) << i;
        cout << "                          ";
        cout << WF[i] << endl;

        /*this portion of the loop does the calculations needed to find the average word length*/

        TotalWords += WF[i];
        TotalLetters += (i * WF[i]);
    }

    cout << "\nTotal Words = " << TotalWords << endl << endl;

    cout << "Total Letters = " << TotalLetters << endl << endl;

    Average = TotalLetters/TotalWords;

    cout << "Average Word Length: " << Average << endl;
}
```

I used "Ain't" in both situations, just for testing purposes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you call this function, and what does your terminal input look like? If you hard code the string does it do the same thing?

Comment: I'll add the rest of the code in there.

Comment: It could be that your terminal is using a different character for quotes - e.g. some kind of locale-specific or "smart quote" ([explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark)) rather than the simple [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) 39 value: you could add a final `else std::cout << "ignoring character " << (int)Input << '\n';` to your `if`/`else` chain to see the character code read: a single right quote *should* be [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) 39 decimal.

Comment: I was assuming the Terminal was using some other value for the quote outside of the traditional ASCII value.  I think I might've tried using the ASCII value, but I don't totally remember.  I'll try it again.

Comment: Can't reproduce. [Works for me](http://rextester.com/DYNT42640)

Comment: What's wrong with `++WordFrequency[TempLengthStorage]`?

Comment: Probably nothing @Beta, I don't always have the best solutions.  Igor, are you on Mac or PC?

Comment: @joe_04_04 The link in igors comment is a link to an online compiler.